# Derivative of quadratic form of matrix in terms of the matrix elements?

Tags: derivatives, quadratic-forms

Suppose I have $b^tAc$ and I try to get the derivative in terms of $A$. How could What is the matrix notational result?

I believe the answer is $bc^t$, isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, the answer is $bc^t$.

The derivative of a scalar with respect to a matrix is calculated as

$\frac{\partial y}{\partial \mathbf{A}} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial y}{\partial a_{11}} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial a_{21}} & \cdots & \frac{\partial y}{\partial a_{p1}}\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial a_{12}} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial a_{22}} & \cdots & \frac{\partial y}{\partial a_{p2}}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial a_{1q}} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial a_{2q}} & \cdots & \frac{\partial y}{\partial a_{pq}}\\
\end{bmatrix}$,

where one have to take into account that the indices of $A$ elements are transposed in the resulting matrix.